# Write to a buffer without visiting it?

Tags: buffers

I am looking for a solution where i can write a string to a **Buffer** without actually visiting it. I want to achieve this purely through an elisp function. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer "temp")
  (insert "my string"))
```

Comment: In that case, you can mark my question as a solution.